# Is it necessary/advisable to remove the default theme in octopress when installing a new one?

Tags: themes, blogs, octopress

I just installed a new theme for my octopress blog. However, I think that since everything from the theme files gets copied in the source files, there is a little mess now. I mean, in the source files are files from the old default theme that I don't use.

It doesn't bother me too much, but I am just wondering whether there is a way to 'uninstall' / remove a theme? Any ideas? Is that achievable? Is it better to remove any old themes before installing a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling a theme is as easy as removing it from the hidden themes directory.

Use

```
rm -rf .themes/UNWANTED_THEME
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, and in my case it got even worse because some include files were there from the classic octopress theme, and there were conflicts.

What worked for me is:

- go into `.themes/<oldtheme>/source` to see what exact files the theme provides
- exclude the corresponding files from `source` folder in the octopress root
- run `rake install[theme]` to install new theme, such as the `classic` theme

Hope it helps